# How to expand the range of merged cells while keeping formatting with VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have the current xlsx file:

[image: Excel Header]

I want to extend the merge of the cells so that they go from B# to J#.

For example, currently B3 to G3 is merged as one cell. I want to extend this to B3 to J3.

How can I accomplish this in VBScript?

Comment: I guess you mean Visual Basic for Applications?

Comment: Assuming you mean VBA vs. vbscript, you could do `Range("B3:J3").Merge` or you could throw some variables and a loop in there to cover a dynamic range.  Whatever you need to accomplish really.  If you really want something like VBS however, then try this `ExcelWorksheet.Range(ExcelWorksheet.Cells(3,2), ExcelWorksheet.Cells(3,10)).Merge`

Comment: No I am using a VBScript, I'm just showing what I want to accomplish with an excel file to make it easier to see. Your answer helped Jason. Do you know how I would edit a border of an entire column?

Comment: it would be something like this: `ExcelWorksheet.Range("B:B").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write the code in the Excel VBE and convert it to VBScript.  You'll have to convert any Excel constants to their values or create constants of your own to hold their values. You also cannot used named parameters in VBScript.

Ranges have a BorderAround method that will add border all around the range.

Excel VBA

Range("B3:J3").BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium, ColorIndex:=xlColorIndexAutomatic

VBScript

Range("B3:J3").BorderAround 1, -4138 ,-4105

Sample VBScript

```
const xlContinuous = 1 
const xlMedium = -4138 
const xlColorIndexAutomatic = -4105 

Dim oExcel, xlWB, xlWS
Set oExcel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Visible = True

Set xlWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set xlWS = xlWB.ActiveSheet

xlWS.Range("B3:J3").Merge

xlWS.Range("B3:J3").BorderAround xlContinuous, xlMedium, xlColorIndexAutomatic

Set xlWB = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score -1):

Select the merged cell, go to the "Merge and Center" drop down menu and click "Unmerge Cell".

Then Select the cells you want it to cover and click "Merge and Center" again. This should also match formatting.

Note: Do this with one set at a time or you will get an error message or mess it up.